# "ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest" error with AJAX request by plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have code like:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: url  // Some URL
});
```

The above code worked perfectly. But, I have a requirement to convert this code to pure JS. So, I did:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.send();
```

But, here when the AJAX request is fired I get this error in rails server log:

> ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest - Security warning: an
>   embedded  tag on another site requested protected JavaScript.
>   If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection
>   on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding.

**NOTE**: I had faced similar error when I passed `format: :js` in `link_to`([Fix I referred](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/950)). But, this happens with pure JavaScript code.

How do I fix this?

Comment: If  jQuery ajax works but xhttp doesn't you can inspect the headers in either request in the console and see what differences their are. It could well be that there is code in your application for `ajaxSend` which executes globally for all jquery ajax calls before a send making it work for jQuery.

Comment: @Fran That's a good suggestion. I see the jQuery request has an additional request header param as `X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest`. I'm gonna try that.

Comment: Ok adding `xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");` got rid of that error in rails. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");` fixed the cross origin error in rails.

Now, the code looks like:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
xhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Rails, in a Hotwire Stimulus controller, I wanted to fetch some data when a user selects a range of dates on a FullCalendar instance. I ran into this error and found all kinds of bad advice everywhere, so I'll fix that bad advice here with what I ended up using (based on the accepted solution):

```
fetch('/path/' + start_date + '/' + end_date,
  {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    },
    credentials: "same-origin",
  })
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    // append to an element here
  });
```

For my particular situation now I just need to change the controller so that it renders a partial and sends the html.